# Get file contents in java script

Tags: javascript

I've a URL that its contents are also JavaScript codes, I want to get the contents of this URL via JavaScript something like to `file_get_contents()` in PHP and show them to the user using the `alert()` function.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest in Javascript to fetch datas from an external URL. Here is a good resource : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp (I usually don't recommend them, but the AJAX tutorial is really good).

Also, this had to be there :

[image: jQuery ownz]

Comment: The link is broken. It would be nice if you can write the solution script in your answer.

Answer (score 17):

you can get the contents from that URL by using jQuery

```
$.get('website_url', function(data) {
     alert(data);
});
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://*****. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://*****' is therefore not allowed access.