# Get file contents in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is something in JavaScript that loads the contents of a given file.

For example, I have a file called `timer.php` which (on certain conditions) prints either a 1 or a 0. I need JavaScript to read it and use it as a variable in order to execute a function.

So something like:

```
function dothis() {

 var timer = getfilecontents(timer.php);

 if(timer == 1) {
   somefunction();
 }
}
```

And thats pretty much it. Is there anything I can use in the cases like this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want the contents of `timer.php`, the contents would be PHP source code.  Instead you want to execute `timer.php` on the server and return the result to the browser.

Comment: Yes, thats true. I want what timer.php produces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file contents in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103664/get-file-contents-in-java-script)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery simplifies AJAX - with jQuery:

```
function dothis() {
    $.get("timer.php", function(data){
        var timer = data;
        if (timer == 1)
            somefunction();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now when i use a loop like this: setInterval(dothis,10000); it says dothis is not defined. Why?

Answer (score -1):

Using the jQuery ajax method you can get the contents of you file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

You can easily get more help about how to use the `ajax` method from jQuery API document or this URL: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/