# How to remove html text attribute tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a paragraph:

```html
<p id="demo">Hi <b>R</b><u>o</u><i>h</i>it! It's soo good to see you</p>
```

How can I replace the word Rohit with Akshat in the same formatting so that I get:
Hi **A**k *s* hat! It's soo good to see you

Comment: Please show us your efforts.

Comment: You must have to use <b> ,<I> , <u> ? Instead you can use `font-style`, so that whenever you want to remove font styles you can remove the style attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```js
var content = document.getElementById('demo').textContent;
document.getElementById('demo').textContent = content;
```

```html
<p id="demo">Hi <b>R</b><u>o</u><i>h</i>it! It's soo good to see you</p>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you soo much

Comment: Well is there a way to replace Rohit by Akshat in the same formatting?? like **A**k _s_ hat

Answer (score 0):

**Just look into this**

var text = $('#demo').text();

console.log(text);      //return "Hi Rohit! It's soo good to see you"

Comment: [NOT ENOUGH jQuery!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103705/1020526)